# Using 'cut' command on Windows

Tags: bash, sh, cut, coreutils

I am trying to run this command line on Windows (I've installed GNU coreutils 8.24)

`echo android:versionCode="3267" | cut -d \" -f 2`

Expected output:
`3267`

However, I am getting error:

`cut: the delimiter must be a single character`

Anyone know how can I use cut command to extract `3267` from `android:versionCode="3267"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I use `cut` to extract `3267` from `android:versionCode="3267"`?

You need to escape the first pair of `"`s:

```
$ echo android\:versionCode=\"3267\" | cut -d \" -f 2
3267
$
```

(tested in Cywin bash)